# How to specify sorting by multiple columns in TypeORM's find method?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

As [in the find-options documentation is written](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md) this can be achieved by something like this ...

```
userRepository.find({
    order: {
        name: "ASC",
        id: "DESC",
    },
})
```

will execute the following query

```
SELECT * FROM "user"
ORDER BY "name" ASC, "id" DESC
```

... I am wondering how the order of the columns can be specified. There is no possibility to put an array of `FindOptionsOrder`s in. The method only accepts an object.

Isn't the order of a JS Record/Object's properties undeterminated?
What if I would like to be secure, that a collection gets ordered first by id and then by the name, if I just swap the properties in the object's definition?

```
userRepository.find({
    order: {
        id: "ASC",
        nams: "DESC",
    },
})
```

BTW: OK, as an ID will be unique is most cases, this makes no sense here - but it's just **their** example.

In my test it is working, the options object seems to maintain the order of set properties. But this extends my question to **How is that possible**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "... technically order is not guaranteed, but practically it always is"

Source: [Order of multiple ORDER BY statements (GitHub issue)](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2192)

Have a look at how ORDER BY statement is constructred in current implementation in Typeorm's `SelectQueryBuilder.ts` in master branch:

```
**
 * Creates "ORDER BY" part of SQL query.
 */
protected createOrderByExpression() {
    const orderBys = this.expressionMap.allOrderBys
    if (Object.keys(orderBys).length > 0)
        return (
            " ORDER BY " +
            Object.keys(orderBys)
                .map((columnName) => {
                    if (typeof orderBys[columnName] === "string") {
                        return (
                            this.replacePropertyNames(columnName) +
                            " " +
                            orderBys[columnName]
                        )
                    } else {
                        return (
                            this.replacePropertyNames(columnName) +
                            " " +
                            (orderBys[columnName] as any).order +
                            " " +
                            (orderBys[columnName] as any).nulls
                        )
                    }
                })
                .join(", ")
        )

    return ""
}
```